# Angular 2 & Webpack: Most errors not logged to the console

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm creating an app using angular 2 and I recently migrated my code from SystemJS to Webpack.

I've noticed that errors thrown by angular are not being logged to the console since I switched to Webpack.

Does anybody know how to fix this and get errors logged to the console again?

**Webpack config**

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const helpers = require('./helpers');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge'); // used to merge webpack configs
const webpackMergeDll = webpackMerge.strategy({ plugins: 'replace' });
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js'); // the settings that are common to prod and dev

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const AddAssetHtmlPlugin = require('add-asset-html-webpack-plugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const NamedModulesPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');

/**
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const METADATA = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }).metadata, {
  host: HOST,
  port: PORT,
  ENV: ENV,
  HMR: HMR
});


const DllBundlesPlugin = require('webpack-dll-bundles-plugin').DllBundlesPlugin;

/**
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
  return webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {

    /**
     * Developer tool to enhance debugging
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/build-performance#sourcemaps
     */
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',

    /**
     * Options affecting the output of the compilation.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
     */
    output: {

      /**
       * The output directory as absolute path (required).
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path
       */
      path: helpers.root('dist'),

      /**
       * Specifies the name of each output file on disk.
       * IMPORTANT: You must not specify an absolute path here!
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename
       */
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',

      /**
       * The filename of the SourceMaps for the JavaScript files.
       * They are inside the output.path directory.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-sourcemapfilename
       */
      sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',

      /** The filename of non-entry chunks as relative path
       * inside the output.path directory.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-chunkfilename
       */
      chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',

      library: 'ac_[name]',
      libraryTarget: 'var',
    },

    module: {

      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'tslint-loader',
              options: {
                configFile: 'tslint.json'
              }
            }
          ],
          exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
        },

        /*
         * css loader support for *.css files (styles directory only)
         * Loads external css styles into the DOM, supports HMR
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /*
         * sass loader support for *.scss files (styles directory only)
         * Loads external sass styles into the DOM, supports HMR
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /**
         * Script loader needed for Cesium imports
         */
        {
          test: /Cesium\.js$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'script-loader'
            }
          ]
        },

        /**
         * Script loader needed for roslib imports
         */
        {
          test: /roslib\.js$/,
          use: [ 'script-loader' ]
        },

      ]

    },

    plugins: [

      /**
       * Plugin: DefinePlugin
       * Description: Define free variables.
       * Useful for having development builds with debug logging or adding global constants.
       *
       * Environment helpers
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
       */
      // NOTE: when adding more properties, make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts
      new DefinePlugin({
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        'process.env': {
          'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        }
      }),

      new DllBundlesPlugin({
        bundles: {
          polyfills: [
            'core-js',
            {
              name: 'zone.js',
              path: 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'
            },
            {
              name: 'zone.js',
              path: 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js'
            },
          ],
          vendor: [
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/forms',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angularclass/hmr',
            'rxjs',
            'roslib',
            'cesium',
            'eventemitter2'
          ]
        },
        dllDir: helpers.root('dll'),
        webpackConfig: webpackMergeDll(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
          devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
          plugins: []
        })
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: AddAssetHtmlPlugin
       * Description: Adds the given JS or CSS file to the files
       * Webpack knows about, and put it into the list of assets
       * html-webpack-plugin injects into the generated html.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/SimenB/add-asset-html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new AddAssetHtmlPlugin([
        { filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('polyfills')}`) },
        { filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('vendor')}`) }
      ]),

      /**
       * Plugin: NamedModulesPlugin (experimental)
       * Description: Uses file names as module name.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/a04ffb928365b19feb75087c63f13cadfc08e1eb
       */
      // new NamedModulesPlugin(),

      /**
       * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
       *
       * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
       */
      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true,
        options: {

        }
      }),

    ],

    /**
     * Webpack Development Server configuration
     * Description: The webpack-dev-server is a little node.js Express server.
     * The server emits information about the compilation state to the client,
     * which reacts to those events.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
     */
    devServer: {
      port: METADATA.port,
      host: METADATA.host,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
      }
    },

    /*
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  });
}
```

**More Webpack config**

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const ngcWebpack = require('ngc-webpack');

/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const AOT = helpers.hasNpmFlag('aot');
const METADATA = {
  title: '',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
  isProd = options.env === 'production';
  return {

    /*
     * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
     * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
     * You can pass false to disable it.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
     */
    //cache: false,

    /*
     * The entry point for the bundle
     * Our Angular.js app
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    entry: {

      'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
      'main':      AOT ? './src/main.browser.aot.ts' :
                  './src/main.browser.ts'

    },

    /*
     * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    resolve: {

      /*
       * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
       */
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

      // An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
      modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],

    },

    /*
     * Options affecting the normal modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
     */
    module: {

      rules: [

        /*
         * Typescript loader support for .ts
         *
         * Component Template/Style integration using `angular2-template-loader`
         * Angular 2 lazy loading (async routes) via `ng-router-loader`
         *
         * `ng-router-loader` expects vanilla JavaScript code, not TypeScript code. This is why the
         * order of the loader matter.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
         * See: https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader
         * See: https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ng-router-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
              options: {
                pretty: !isProd,
                prod: isProd
              }
            },
            { // MAKE SURE TO CHAIN VANILLA JS CODE, I.E. TS COMPILATION OUTPUT.
              loader: 'ng-router-loader',
              options: {
                loader: 'async-import',
                genDir: 'compiled',
                aot: AOT
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
              options: {
                configFileName: 'tsconfig.webpack.json'
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
            }
          ],
          exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
        },

        /*
         * Json loader support for *.json files.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          use: 'json-loader'
        },

        /*
         * to string and css loader support for *.css files (from Angular components)
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /*
         * to string and sass loader support for *.scss files (from Angular components)
         * Returns compiled css content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /* Raw loader support for *.html
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },

        /* 
         * File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
         */
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },

        /* File loader for supporting fonts, for example, in CSS files.
        */
        { 
          test: /\.(eot|woff2?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        }

      ],

    },

    /*
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [
      new AssetsPlugin({
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
        prettyPrint: true
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
       * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
       */
      new CheckerPlugin(),
      /*
       * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
       * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
       * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
       */
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'polyfills',
        chunks: ['polyfills']
      }),
      // This enables tree shaking of the vendor modules
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        chunks: ['main'],
        minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource)
      }),
      // Specify the correct order the scripts will be injected in
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: ContextReplacementPlugin
       * Description: Provides context to Angular's use of System.import
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#contextreplacementplugin
       * See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
       */
      new ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)src(\\|\/)linker/,
        helpers.root('src'), // location of your src
        {
          // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
        }
      ),

      /*
       * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
       *
       * Copies project static assets.
       *
       * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
       */
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
        { from: 'src/meta'}
      ]),


      /*
       * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
       * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
       * which changes every compilation.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html',
        title: METADATA.title,
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
        metadata: METADATA,
        inject: 'head'
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Enhances html-webpack-plugin functionality
       * with different deployment options for your scripts including:
       *
       * See: https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
        defaultAttribute: 'defer'
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: HtmlElementsPlugin
       * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
       *
       * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
       * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
       * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
       *
       * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
       * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
       *
       * Example:
       *  Adding this plugin configuration
       *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
       *    headTags: { ... }
       *  })
       *
       *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
       *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
       *
       * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       */
      new HtmlElementsPlugin({
        headTags: require('./head-config.common')
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
       *
       * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
       */
      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),

      // Fix Angular 2
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)async/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)collection/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)errors/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)lang/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)math/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/math.js')
      ),

      new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin({
        disabled: !AOT,
        tsConfig: helpers.root('tsconfig.webpack.json'),
        resourceOverride: helpers.root('config/resource-override.js')
      })

    ],

    /*
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  };
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
// Angular 2 imports
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import { ROUTING } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ROUTING,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
     ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you show where do you bootstrap the application? I can only see the AppModule here.

Comment: Just answered by own Q (see answer below), thanks for taking a look though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer myself.

The Angular error handler was already throwing an error, which was expected but not a fatal error (or so I thought), and it seems that this prevented the error handler from logging anything else to the console.

Once I fixed the initial error, my app then started to log other errors.

Lesson learnt!